# How to connect iOS 11 App with SharePoint 2013 on-premises

Tags: iphone, swift, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, ios11

I have some SharePoint 2013 libraries and lists and now I want to connect these with my iOS 11 App (coded in Swift 4). In my App I want to retrieve data from my SP lists and send data back to SharePoint also. Does anybody know how to do this in Swift 4? I don't know how to authenticate my users - thank you so much!

Comment: Too many problems asked in the same question without sufficient details for any. Is it an iOS question? Is it a sharepoint question? Is it an active directory question? Or is it a general app architecture question? Please specify the exact problem with sufficient details around it including source code and screen shots.

Comment: It is an iOS and SharePoint 2013 question of course. When I use this code [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926996/swift-3-ntlm-authentication) and passing my credentials I get the response of "unknown authentication method". When I use NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust instead I get "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource" error (Status Code 403).

Comment: Just to clarify some points: I have a SharePoint 2013 on-premises solution and want to connect my SharePoint with my iOS 11 App (I use Swift 4). All I want to do is creating forms with Eureka Framework and send my form data to my SharePoint 2013 and fetch list data (text and files) in my App from my SharePoint too.

Answer (score 0):

We can use Swift to call SharePoint REST API to retrieve data.

About how to do authentication, we can use Swift to do Windows NTLM to achieve this.

More information we can refer to this thread: [Swift 3 NTLM authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926996/swift-3-ntlm-authentication)

More information about SharePoint REST API for your reference: [SharePoint REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints)